# Python Data Frame Matplotlib - plot x-axis time formatting issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

My dataframe contains date/time and open price.. i am trying to plot them with date/time in xaxis and price in y-axis but the labels in x-axis not getting formatted properly.. also the plot is very weird.. doesnt make any sense.. please see below my entire code and the chart output in link

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

data = pd.read_csv("2020BNNF.csv")
print(data)
import datetime
dat1 = data.loc[data["Ticker"] == "BANKNIFTY18500CE"]
dat1["dttime"] = pd.to_datetime(dat1["Date/Time"])
#dat1["dttime"] = datetime.datetime.strptime(dat1["Date/Time"], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
dat1.sort_values("Date/Time",ascending=True)
print(dat1.head(10))
plt.figure(figsize=(18,8))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = dat1["dttime"]
y = dat1["Open"]

# Major ticks every 6 months.
fmt_wk = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(fmt_wk)

# Minor ticks every month.
fmt_day = mdates.MonthLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(fmt_day)

# Text in the x axis will be displayed in 'YYYY-mm' format.
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'))

# Round to nearest years.
#datemin = np.datetime64(dat1['Date/Time'][0], 'Y')
#datemax = np.datetime64(dat1['Date/Time'][-1], 'Y') + np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
#ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)

# Format the coords message box, i.e. the numbers displayed as the cursor moves
# across the axes within the interactive GUI.
#ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y')
#ax.format_ydata = lambda x: f'${x:.2f}'  # Format the price.
#ax.grid(True)

# Rotates and right aligns the x labels, and moves the bottom of the
# axes up to make room for them.
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

graph output:

[image]

Comment: sample data from your CSV...  `dat1["dttime"] = pd.to_datetime(dat1["Date/Time"])
dat1.sort_values("Date/Time",ascending=True)
`. why sort by column that is a string?

Comment: @RobRaymond i am actually trying to sort the dttime column in ascending order to see the earliest date from which data is available

Comment: this is my corrected code

Comment: dat1["dttime"] = pd.to_datetime(dat1["Date/Time"])
#dat1["dttime"] = datetime.datetime.strptime(dat1["Date/Time"], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
dat1.sort_values("dttime",ascending=True)
print(dat1.head(10))

Comment: output is              Ticker            Date/Time    Open    High     Low   Close  \
0  BANKNIFTY18500CE  20-05-2020 09:19:00  749.85  781.90  749.85  781.90   
1  BANKNIFTY18500CE  20-05-2020 09:21:00  781.90  781.90  770.00  772.00   
2  BANKNIFTY18500CE  20-05-2020 09:23:00  772.00  772.00  750.15  750.15   
3  BANKNIFTY18500CE  20-05-2020 09:30:00  750.15  750.15  731.10  731.10

Comment: output is interesting but not what I asked for... input and in the question.  that way you will get far more help on SO.   Take a look at best practice questions